# Seamlessly powering 12v CPU fan with regulating speeds

Tags: batteries, dc, switch-mode-power-supply, backup

I am trying to have an economical and reliable control system to seamlessly power two 12v, 0.3a CPU fans with varying speeds while also charging a 12v 7ah lead acid battery for backup. I could not find a ready-made product to buy, can somebody please suggest me on how I can achieve this in a cost effective way? Thanks.

Comment: Consider using a COTS charger for the battery and a small MCU for the fans.

Answer (score 0):

As the battery is for backup, I assume it's a gel-cell type, so suitable for float charging at a constant voltage.

Buy or make a float battery charger, capable of providing at least the 600mA the fans require, set to around 2.25 to 2.3 volts per cell. A linear regulator would be fine. Make sure the charger can tolerate the input power supply dissappearing without discharging the battery.

Run the fan controllers directly from the float charged battery.